# Can the following jQuery code be simplified?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created 6 buttons and using jQuery I am able to get block of data on click of each buttons. I want to know whether the jQuery code written can be minimized? How to achieve the minimized code?

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("#text1").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text1").hide();
  });
});

$("#button2").click(function() {
  $("#text2").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text2").hide();
  });
});

$("#button3").click(function() {
  $("#text3").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text3").hide();
  });
});

$("#button4").click(function() {
  $("#text4").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text4").hide();
  });
});

$("#button5").click(function() {
  $("#text5").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text5").hide();
  });
});

$("#button6").click(function() {
  $("#text6").show();
  $(".close").show();
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#text6").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.block h1 {
  margin-top: 160px;
}

.close {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -220px;
  margin-left: 560px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text1">
      <h1> Button1 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button1"> Button_1 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text2">
      <h1> Button2 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button2"> Button_2 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text3">
      <h1> Button3 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button3"> Button_3 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text4">
      <h1> Button4 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button4"> Button_4 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text5">
      <h1> Button5 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button5"> Button_5 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text6">
      <h1> Button6 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button6"> Button_6 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link of the above mentioned code . Please have a look .https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6xmfL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button.button").click(function() {
  $(this).prev('.block').show();
  $(".close").show();
  
});



$(".close").click(function() {
    $(".block:visible").hide();
  });
```

```css
#header {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.block h1 {
  margin-top: 160px;
}

.close {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -220px;
  margin-left: 560px;
}

.button{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text1">
      <h1> Button1 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" class="button"> Button_1 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text2">
      <h1> Button2 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button2" class="button"> Button_2 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text3">
      <h1> Button3 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button3" class="button"> Button_3 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text4">
      <h1> Button4 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button4" class="button"> Button_4 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text5">
      <h1> Button5 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button5" class="button"> Button_5 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text6">
      <h1> Button6 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button6" class="button"> Button_6 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
```

1. Add a common class to each button
2. use this context to tell the clicked button
3. Use `prev()` to get the previous div that needs to be shown
4. use selector `.block:visible` to select the visible block to hide

Comment: Much more complicated than necessary with the code given

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `jQuery` code for this

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().show()
    $(this).prev().find('.close').show()
});

$(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.block').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest - without changing class names:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(".close")) $(this).closest('.block').hide();
  else {
    $(this).prev().show();
    $(this).prev().find('.close').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.block h1 {
  margin-top: 160px;
}

.close {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -220px;
  margin-left: 560px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text1">
      <h1> Button1 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button1"> Button_1 </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="block" id="text2">
      <h1> Button2 </h1>
      <h5> Displays block of elements </h5>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </div>
    <button id="button2"> Button_2 </button>
  </div>


  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for the answer for the given ids and class names without adding extra stuff..

Comment: You are welcome. I think it is the more elegant version assuming you only have two kinds of buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.block').show();
    $(this).prev('.block').find('.close').show();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.block').hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe encapsulated in a reusable function.

```
customFn("button1","text1","close");
customFn("button2","text2","close");
customFn("button3","text3","close");

function customFn(buttonId,textId,closeClass){
  $("#"+buttonId).unbind("click").bind("click",function() {
      $("#"+textId).show();
      $("."+closeClass).show();
      $("."+closeClass).unbind("click").bind("click",function() {
          $("#"+textId).hide();
    });
  });
 }

 //unbind("click").bind("click" prevents unnecessary events as stated in the comments
```

Comment: Then you need one for each button. That is no improvement. At least have only one function and extract the number or something

Comment: Yes that was my intention. You know you can comment without a down vote to give the answer author an opportunity to correct their mistakes.

Comment: Thanks yeah not very intuitive doing this from and iPhone.

Comment: This needs one line per button - why not a loop? Or just look at my answer for the simplest version ;)

Comment: `$("#header .block").each(function(i) { i++; customFn("button"+i,"text"+i,"close"); });`

Comment: And you now assign a new event handler to every close for every click made.